# selectcommand's weird behaviour

Tags: php, mysql

I have strange problem. If I use

```
"SELECT filed1, field2…. FROM some_table WHERE field1 LIKE 'something'"
```

in `"$grid->SelectCommand"` everything is working as it should, but if I use variable

```
"SELECT filed1, field2…. FROM some_table WHERE field1 LIKE '$get_variable'"
```

I do not get expected result.

Comment: How is this related to jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Either $get_variable is not in the current scope, or it does not have the value you think it does. However, LIKE is intended to work with wildcard characters (%). If not, you would just check for equality.

Also, you mis-spelt field1 (in comparison to field2).

Comment: well i am echo'ing the value above,its displaying perfectly,infact the value is coming from parent page through URL,so its very simple,just GET needs to be used,same page,same code with different db table works but not that table.funny part is,instead of GET if u directly give that value to check,it displays :)

Comment: What is a typical value for $get_variable, and did you test it both ways with this value? You can also surround it with curly brackets within the string ".. LIKE '{$get_variable}'". This identifies the variable to PHP explicity, although it shouldn't really be necessary because the apostrophes don't confuse PHP. Worth a try though.